# How to replace backslash dollar sign in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a text where dollar sign is already escaped. How to replace `\$` with `$`?

```
month=\$(date +%m)
```

becomes

```
month=$(date +%m)
```

Comment: Escape the backslash and dollar sign in the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar: The way I did it didn't work. `\\\$`

Comment: Post your code in the question.

Comment: No regex is required `str = str.replace('\\$', '$')`

Comment: @anubhava Unless there are multiple of them in the string.

Comment: @Xaqron My answer uses the same regexp that you said didn't work. What's the difference?

Comment: @Barmar: I did it in the wrong logical branch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since backslash and dollar sign both have special meaning in a regexp, you need to escape both of them.

```js
let str = 'month=\\$(date +%m)';
console.log('before', str);
str = str.replace(/\\\$/g, '$');
console.log('after', str);
```